# Did Jean-Baptiste Mouron serve 100 years of jail time — and live to be free again?

Tags: history

I've came across a ~2005 email thread with "life curiosities" that stated:

> 49. Jean-Baptiste Mouron, de 17 años de edad, fue acusado de
>     incendiario y condenado a galeras durante cien años y un día. Mouron
>     cumplió el castigo integro y quedo libre a la edad de 117 años.

Which roughly translates to:

> 49. Jean-Baptiste Mouron, aged 17, was charged with arson for 100 years and 1 day. Mouron served the whole time, and got free aged 117.

I've found a couple of Spanish-speaking websites mentioning the same story, but with no sources — and mostly the same wording (I never heard the phrase "condenado a galeras" here in Argentina).

**Did Jean-Baptiste Mouron actually exist? Are there any reliable sources confirming the story, or is it an internet myth?**

Comment: For people trying to research this, [the similar threads](https://vk.com/wall-178449167_24085?lang=en) (unsupported) I've found point to him being sentenced in 1684. Some of them claim he appears as a record in Guinness, but I'm pretty sure this is inaccurate; they claim he lived to the age of 124, but Guiness's "Oldest person ever to have lived" record is only 122 years and 164 days (for a French woman). I'm incredibly skeptical, especially since some of the source claim he was a galley slave for all 100 years, and there is *zero* chance anyone lived to that age as a functional galley slave.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I found [another site](https://supercurioso.com/puede-un-hombre-sobrevivir-a-100-anos-de-terrible-condena/) (in Spanish) claiming Mouron died only a few days after he was released. That would still make him the oldest *man* in history - the Guinness record is currently held by Jiroemon Kimura, who died at 116 - but more crucially, it seems there are inconsistencies in the story.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it's in fact exceedingly unlikely that anyone lived to over 100 years at all in 17th century France, let alone as a prisoner of any kind :) As a slave I can see someone courting favours and being placed on milder duties and better treatment (including diet) allowing for a longer lifespan (from galley slave to personal servant of some high ranking official for example) but that too wouldn't allow such a long lifespan.

Comment: Pre-revolution, documents should have existed for baptism, marriage and sepulture, at least for Catholics. If those documents existed, then they should have been kept in parochial archives, which are now kept at the archives of the relevant *département*, and a double might exist at the relevant city hall. These may or may not be available online. If you know where they were born/died, and when, that would be a way to confirm it.

Comment: @jwenting: I agree this particular story sounds impossible, but it’s not implausible that there were *some* centenarians in that period.  Verification is difficult, but see e.g. [Hynes 1995, *The Oldest Old in Pre-Industrial Britain:
Centenarians before 1800 - Fact or Fiction?*](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/books/monograph2/the%20oldest.htm), which argues in favour of their existence — though [Jeune 1995, *In Search of the First Centenarians*](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/books/monograph2/search.htm), in the same volume, argues for the contrary.

Comment: @PLL I had a number of relatives born in the 1860s and 70s who lived to be 100 or older.  Yes, much of their lives were lived after the advent of antibiotics, but ... only the last 20 or 30 years.  Had they been born 50 or 100 years earlier, their lives wouldn't have been very different.  It's not at all implausible that people lived to that age in the 18th century.

Comment: "Condenar a galeras" was a quite common punishment for many crimes not warranting a death penalty. It was tantamount to one, nevertheless. You were made into an oarsman in the galley fleets that most countries possessed in the Mediterranean sea. Life expectancy for these poor prisoners was but a handful of years. Initially in Spain the sentence to the galleys was for life, but it was reduced to a maximum of ten years, since nearly nobody survived that much.

Answer (score 21):

The source of this is the 1930s American serial *Ripley's Believe It or Not*, which gives a place, Toulon, a date range, 1684-1784, and a citation: [Jean Marteilhe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Marteilhe)'s *Mémoires d'un protestant, condamné aux galères de France pour cause de religion*. However, this citation is impossible, as that book was written in 1757, and Marteilhe died in 1777. The end!

Well, except not really! Because there is a kernel of truth:

> In 1684, Louis XIV had five hundred Huguenot prisoners marched in chains from Paris to Toulon, where they were condemned to the living death of the galleys. (S. Dearden, *A Nest of Corsairs: The Fighting Karamanlis of Tripoli*, 1976)

Marteilhe's book does not mention this anywhere, so this claim seems separate from the impossible citation; the person making the claim seems to have been reading about galley slaves somewhere. However, I was unable to follow this trail any further; Gallica and [RetroNews](https://www.retronews.fr/) may have more details but my research skills are failing me today.